# Troubleshooting a Real-Time Notification System with Ruby on Rails and ActionCable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, real-time, actioncable

I have implemented a real-time notification system in my Ruby on Rails application using ActionCable to enable WebSocket communication between the server and clients. However, when a new notification is created, it is not being pushed to the client-side in real-time as expected. I suspect there might be an extreme level bug in my code, but I can't seem to pinpoint it.

I have followed the standard implementation of ActionCable in Ruby on Rails:

Created a Notification model to represent each notification.
Set up a NotificationChannel for handling ActionCable subscriptions.

```
# app/models/notification.rb
class Notification < ApplicationRecord
  after_create_commit { broadcast }

  private

  def broadcast
    ActionCable.server.broadcast("notifications:#{user_id}", {
      notification: self
    })
  end
end

# app/channels/notification_channel.rb
class NotificationChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "notifications:#{current_user.id}"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when the channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

Used the after_create_commit callback in my Notification model to broadcast the notification to the client.
I expected that when a new notification is created, it would be broadcasted to the client-side, and the JavaScript code would receive and render the notification on the page in real-time.

```
// app/javascript/channels/notification_channel.js
import consumer from "./consumer"

consumer.subscriptions.create("NotificationChannel", {
  connected() {
    console.log("Connected to the notification channel")
  },

  disconnected() {
    console.log("Disconnected from the notification channel")
  },

  received(data) {
    console.log("Received notification:", data)
    // Render the notification on the page
  }
})
```

What actually happened:

Despite setting up everything correctly, as far as I can tell, the notifications are not being pushed to the client-side in real-time. The JavaScript code does not seem to be receiving the notifications as expected, and no errors are being displayed in the console.